# Json.dump failing with 'must be unicode, not str' TypeError

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I have a json file which happens to have a multitude of Chinese and Japanese (and other language) characters. I'm loading it into my python 2.7 script using `io.open` as follows:

```
with io.open('multiIdName.json', encoding="utf-8") as json_data:
    cards = json.load(json_data)
```

I add a new property to the json, all good. Then I attempt to write it back out to another file:

```
with io.open("testJson.json",'w',encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        json.dump(cards, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

That's when I get the error `TypeError: must be unicode, not str`

I tried writing the outfile as a binary (`with io.open("testJson.json",'wb') as outfile:`), but I end up with stuff this:

```
{"multiverseid": 262906, "name": "\u00e6\u00b8\u00b8\u00e9\u009a\u00bc\u00e7\u008b\u00ae\u00e9\u00b9\u00ab", "language": "Chinese Simplified"}
```

I thought opening and writing it in the same encoding would be enough, as well as the ensure_ascii flag, but clearly not. I just want to preserve the characters that existed in the file before I run my script, without them turning into \u's.

Comment: I'm not sure. I believe it's because you're opening the file-pointer as a utf-8 encoded file but you're dumping a `string` type object (`cards`).

Comment: Ah, should've mentioned, cards is a json object: ```cards = json.load(json_data)```

Comment: what is the new property you add? is it possible to write a [Minimal Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
with io.open("testJson.json",'w',encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
  outfile.write(unicode(json.dumps(cards, ensure_ascii=False)))
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks. I presume the outfile.write takes the output from json.dumps and then writes it to the file?

Comment: Great :) Yes. the outfile.write(content) - writes the content to the outfile. While outfile refers to "testJson.json" file. see more in https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Danger! You've got an implied str->Unicode conversion, without an encoding defined. In Python 2.x, the default encoding is ASCII, so you will get a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception if your JSON contains non-ASCII chars

Comment: You can have 8-bit strings given to json, and the output would still break.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this error is the completely stupid behaviour of `json.dumps` in Python 2:

```
>>> json.dumps({'a': 'a'}, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"a": "a"}'
>>> json.dumps({'a': u'a'}, ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"a": "a"}'
>>> json.dumps({'a': 'ä'}, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"a": "\xc3\xa4"}'
>>> json.dumps({u'a': 'ä'}, ensure_ascii=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 210, in encode
    return ''.join(chunks)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This coupled with the fact that `io.open` with `encoding` set only accepts `unicode` objects (which by itself is right), leads to problems.

The return type is completely dependent on whatever is the type of keys or values in the dictionary, if `ensure_ascii=False`, but `str` is returned always if `ensure_ascii=True`. If you can accidentally set 8-bit strings to dictionaries, you cannot blindly convert this return type to `unicode`, because you *need* to set the encoding, presumably UTF-8:

```
>>> x = json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False)
>>> if isinstance(x, str):
...     x = unicode(x, 'UTF-8')
```

In **this** case I believe you can use the `json.dump` to write to an open binary file; however if you need to do something more complicated with the resulting object, you probably need the above code.

---

One solution is to end all this encoding/decoding madness by switching to Python 3.

Comment: I think your answer better answers the question. Wanna add the write part to your answer and I'll delete my answer?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack naah busy now, and I hit repcap today already :D

Comment: If I managed to convert my script to py3, how would the encoding handling change?

Answer (score 3):

The JSON module handles encoding and decoding for you, so you can simply open the input and output files in binary mode. The JSON module assumes UTF-8 encoding, but can be changed using `encoding` attribute on the `load()` and `dump()` methods.

```
with open('multiIdName.json', 'rb') as json_data:
    cards = json.load(json_data)
```

then:

```
with open("testJson.json", 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(cards, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Thanks to @Antti Haapala, Python 2.x JSON module gives either Unicode or str depending on the contents of the object.

You will have to add a sense check to ensure the result is a Unicode before writing through `io`:

```
with io.open("testJson.json", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    my_json_str = json.dumps(my_obj, ensure_ascii=False)
    if isinstance(my_json_str, str):
        my_json_str = my_json_str.decode("utf-8")

    outfile.write(my_json_str)
```

Comment: When I do that I get: ```UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)```

Comment: Are you sure you set the `b` mode on both `open()` calls?

Comment: Yep I'm sure. It was on the json.dump line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import codecs
with codecs.open("test.json","w") as file:
    json.dump(my_list, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: For best practices, let your answer conform to the used cases of questions