# Handling escaped unicode characters from JSON response

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

I'm receiving a list of location names like this

```
region_response = json.loads(requests.get(region_req_url).text)
```

Many of the names have characters represented like `Tor\u00f6 Stenstrand` in the response, where that place name would be `Torö Stenstrand`.

I'm then adding some of the received elements to a dictionary and saving that to a new JSON file

```
with open('spots.json', 'w') as wf:
    json.dump(results, wf, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, indent=4)
```

The resulting file also has the escaped characters like `\u00f6` but I need this to have the actual representations like `ö`.

My work so far is in [this repo](https://github.com/mrbirl/Spot-Lister), specifically in [magicseaweed.py](https://github.com/mrbirl/Spot-Lister/blob/master/magicseaweed.py) and [windguru.py](https://github.com/mrbirl/Spot-Lister/blob/master/windguru.py).

Apologies if this has been answered before, or if my description/assumptions above are incorrect - I've been trying to work this out for quite a while now, but I don't think I understand the area enough to know exactly what I should be looking for or reading up on! Any help/suggestions/pointers would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working :) First I added encoding to the `json.loads`...

```
response = requests.get(region_req_url)
response = requests.utils.get_unicode_from_response(response)
region_response = json.loads(response, encoding='utf-8')
```

Then after trying Sijan's answer above I was getting errors (shown in comment), and when trying to fix the error I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003023/json-dump-failing-with-must-be-unicode-not-str-typeerror), and that solution has worked. So to write to my JSON file I'm doing...

```
with io.open("results.json",'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    outfile.write(unicode(json.dumps(results, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)))
```

Now place names are writing to the JSON file like `Torö Stenstrand`.

Answer (score 1):

I once solve this issue with `io` module as follows

```
import io
j = {'d': '中', 'e': 'a'}
with io.open('myfile.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
   json.dumps(j, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

output:

```
    {"d": "中", "e": "a"}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm getting an error because my dictionary contains strings not unicode `TypeError: must be unicode, not str` - so the escaped characters like `\u00f6` are in string format and will need to be converted to unicode.

I've tried `unidict = {k.decode('utf8'): v.decode('utf8') for k, v in results.items()}` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705274/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-str-to-unicode) but getting error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'`, so I think I'm missing something here.